# How To download multiple csv files from a list of urls using Regex+ for loop?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying all day to download some csv files with no luck.
I have a list of urls that i would like my script to visit, then extract the href attribute from some anchors check if it matches certain regex pattern and download them into a folder "example.com/*.csv"

Im using macOs , python 3.7.2 , i've only tried it on this machine , but once i'll make it work im planning to move it to a linux machine. I've started with selenium and geckodriver , then i found out that i really didn't need it and could make it with BeautifulSoup + requests.

As i said i've been modifying it all day, with no luck , this is the final version , taken from another thread from here:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    _URL = 'http://example.com/words'
    _URLD = str(_URL.strip('words'))

    # functional
    r = requests.get(_URL)
    soup = bs(r.text)
    urls = []
    names = []
    for i, link in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
        _FULLURL = _URLD + link.get('href')
        if _FULLURL.endswith('.csv'):
            urls.append(_FULLURL)
            names.append(soup.select('a')[i].attrs['href'])
            print(_FULLURL)
            requests.get(_FULLURL)
```

With what i have right now, i can see that the console prints all the urls,  but can't figure out where to add the regex pattern so that only the urls with the following pattern can be downloaded.

```
linkRegex = re.compile(r'/name-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+.csv')
```

And then actually writing the csv files to 'example.com/*.csv'

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the question: are you looking for `print(linkRegex .search(_FULLURL).group(0))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the checking '_FULLURL.endswith('.csv')' with regex matching. The save the file using urllib.urlretrieve(). For example, if you want to save to a folder called 'example.com/' in the same directory as the python script:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib

_URL = 'http://example.com/words'
_URLD = str(_URL.strip('words'))

# functional
r = requests.get(_URL)
soup = bs(r.text)
urls = []
names = []
linkRegex = re.compile(r'/name-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+.csv')
for i, link in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
    _FULLURL = _URLD + link.get('href')
    filename_match_obj = lingRegex.search(_FULLURL)
    if filename_match_obj is not None:
        urls.append(_FULLURL)
        names.append(soup.select('a')[i].attrs['href'])
        print(_FULLURL)
        urllib.urlretrieve(_FULLURL, 'example.com' + filename_match_obj.group())
```

Comment: Using the debugger from VSCode , it seems the filename_match_obj never passes the condition , so its always NONE here is a screenshot : https://imgur.com/h7Qfoug

Comment: You are right. The correct thing to use is "search" instead of "match" as @Gsk said in comment. Code fixed.

Comment: Yes!! @Tim It worked!! Thank you! Thank you!
Im gonna edit some typos;